# Exercise on Fibonacci Numbers

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

Consider, for positive $n$, the identity

$$ x^n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} F_{n,k} \, x^{\left(1+ \left\lceil \frac{k-1}{2} \right\rceil\right)} (x-1) ^{\left\lfloor \frac{k-1}{2}\right\rfloor}$$

and prove that the sum $F_n= F_{n,1} + F_{n,2} + \cdots + F_{n,n}$ is the $n$-th Fibonacci number satisfying the relations $F_1 = F_2 = 1$ and $F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}$ for $n>2$.

Anyone knows how to solve it?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your questions.

Comment: $F_n$ may be Fibonacci numbers, but what is $F_{n,k}$? The relation $F_n=F_{n,1}+\ldots+F_{n,n}$ is not very enlightening without a clear definition.

Comment: @Professor Vector: Although I up voted your comment I have just noticed that all the numbers $F_{n,k}$ can be deduced from the equation for $x^n$ without reference to the Fibonacci Numbers. So although left unstated the equation for $x^n$ is the implicit definition for $F_{n,k}$. For example in the case of $x^5$ and $F_{5,k}$ we can deduce that $F_{5,5}=1$, $2F_{5,5}=F_{5,4}$, $F_{5,5}=F_{5,3}$, $F_{5,3}=F_{5,2}$ and $F_{5,1}=0$. Finally giving $F_5=5$.

Comment: @James Arathoon I've suspected that myself, in the meantime. As it seems, the identity uniquely determines $F_{n,k}$, though that's not trivial. And then, it should be possible to derive recursions proving the claim, eventually.

Comment: @ProfessorVector The answer of James Arathoon is correct, Fn,k is uniquely determinated by the identity.

Comment: @JamesArathoon can you please explain me how you arrived to say that $F_{5,5} =1,  2F_{5,5} = F_{5,4}$ etc..., thank you!

Comment: If you expand out the sum for $x^n$ then in the case $n=5$ you end up with $$x^5=F_{5,1}x^1(x-1)^0+F_{5,2}x^2(x-1)^0+F_{5,3}x^2(x-1)^1+F_{5,4}x^3(x-1)^1+F_{5,5}x^3(x-1)^2,$$ $x^5$ can only come from the last term which fixes $F_{5,5}=1$ and so on.

Comment: @JamesArathoon thanks but now I understand why I didn't think about this way before, it was because the original text have 3 at the denominator of the floor

Comment: Then, there's a typo in the original text: as it is now, the RHS is $O(x^{5n/6+1})$, so the identity is impossible for $n>6$.

Comment: I'm the one who translated from image to MathJax.  I was pretty careful, I believe, and both denominators were 2.  As @ProfessorVector says, it can't be that the denominator of the floor is 3.

Comment: Incidentally, you can still see the original image if you click on "edited X hours ago" and look at the original post.  While it's not the clearest image, I'd be hard pressed to find a 3 in that formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely not the most direct proof, but should shed some light on the question.  The table of the $F_{n,k}$ numbers can be generated by this simple MATLAB program

```
function table = fibtable(nrows)
  table = zeros(nrows);
  for n = 1:nrows
    M = fibident(n);
    row = M \ [zeros(n-1,1); 1];
    table(n,1:n) = row.';
  end
end

function M = fibident(n)
  M = zeros(n);
  for k=1:n
    a = 1 + ceil((k-1)/2);
    b = floor((k-1)/2);
    for d = 0:b
      M(a+d, k) = (-1).^(b-d) * nchoosek(b,d);
    end
  end
end
```

The program is based on the observation, also made in the comments to the question, that the identity should be interpreted as the identity of two polynomials of real variable.  For 18 rows, we get

$$\scriptsize
\begin{matrix}
  1 \\
  0 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 3 & 3 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 5 & 4 & 6 & 3 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 6 & 5 & 10 & 6 & 4 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 7 & 6 & 15 & 10 & 10 & 4 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 8 & 7 & 21 & 15 & 20 & 10 & 5 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 9 & 8 & 28 & 21 & 35 & 20 & 15 & 5 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 10 & 9 & 36 & 28 & 56 & 35 & 35 & 15 & 6 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 11 & 10 & 45 & 36 & 84 & 56 & 70 & 35 & 21 & 6 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 12 & 11 & 55 & 45 & 120 & 84 & 126 & 70 & 56 & 21 & 7 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 13 & 12 & 66 & 55 & 165 & 120 & 210 & 126 & 126 & 56 & 28 & 7 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 14 & 13 & 78 & 66 & 220 & 165 & 330 & 210 & 252 & 126 & 84 & 28 & 8 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 15 & 14 & 91 & 78 & 286 & 220 & 495 & 330 & 462 & 252 & 210 & 84 & 36 & 8 & 1
\end{matrix}
$$

It then becomes apparent that the columns of the table (except the first) are  the diagonals of Pascal's triangle, which are related to the Fibonacci numbers (See, for example, [here](https://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=3617&view=htmls).)  In particular,

$$ F_{n,k} = \binom{n-\left\lceil \frac{k}{2}\right\rceil - 1}{n-k} \enspace,$$

which holds for $1 \leq k \leq n$ if we stipulate that $\binom{a}{b} = 0$ when $b < 0$ and $\binom{a}{0} = 1$ also for negative $a$.

---

Let $S_n = \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n} F_{n,k}.$  It's easy to verify that $S_n = F_n$ for $1 \leq n \leq 3$.  We show that $S_{n+2} = S_{n} + S_{n+1}$ for $n > 1$, hence proving that $S_n = F_n$ for all positive $n$.

Taking into account that $F_{n,1} = 0$ and $F_{n,2} = F_{n,n} = 1$ for all $n > 1$, we line up the appropriate members of the two sums and then apply the basic identity,

$$ \binom{a}{b} + \binom{a}{b+1} = \binom{a+1}{b+1} \enspace,$$

which holds for $0 \leq b \leq a$.  In detail,

$$\begin{align}
S_n + S_{n+1} &= \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n-1} \binom{n - \left\lceil \frac{k}{2} \right\rceil - 1}{n-k} + \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n+1} \binom{n + 1 - \left\lceil \frac{k}{2} \right\rceil - 1}{n+1-k} + 1 \\
&= 0 + 1 + \sum_{3 \leq k \leq n+1} \binom{n + 1 - \left\lceil \frac{k}{2} \right\rceil - 1}{n+2-k} + \sum_{3 \leq k \leq n+1} \binom{n + 1 - \left\lceil \frac{k}{2} \right\rceil - 1}{n+1-k} + 1 \\
&= 0 + 1 + \sum_{3 \leq k \leq n+1} \left[ \binom{n + 1 - \left\lceil \frac{k}{2} \right\rceil - 1}{n+2-k} + \binom{n + 1 - \left\lceil \frac{k}{2} \right\rceil - 1}{n+1-k}\right] + 1 \\
&= F_{n+2,1} + F_{n+2,2} + \sum_{3 \leq k \leq n+1} \binom{n + 2 - \left\lceil \frac{k}{2} \right\rceil - 1}{n+2-k} + F_{n+2,n+2} \\
&= \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n+2} \binom{n + 2 - \left\lceil \frac{k}{2} \right\rceil - 1}{n+2-k} \\
&= S_{n+2} \enspace.
\end{align}$$

---

Inspection of the matrix above suggested a formula for $F_{n,k}$.  It remains to prove that the suggestion was correct.  We'll start by revisiting the program that produces the table of the $F_{n,k}$ coefficients.

If we look at a few matrices produced by `fibident`, we'll see that they have a very interesting structure:

$$\small
M_5 = \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -2 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
~~~~~~
M_7 = \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -2 & 1 & -1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -2 & 3 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -3 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \enspace.
$$
Each matrix is a submatrix of all larger matrices and the matrices are triangular, with a diagonal of all ones (which implies they are unimodular).  Therefore we only need to generate one matrix and invert it to get (the transpose of) the table.  (The right hand sides of all our systems of linear equations are the columns of the identity matrix.)  Our revised code does just that.

```
function [tab, M] = fibmatrices(n)
  M = fibident(n);
  tab = inv(M).';
end
```

This revision also suggests that we can prove the correctness of our guess for the coefficients by proving that the transpose of the matrix defined by our $F_{n,k}$'s is the inverse of the $M$ matrix above.  We write the expression of the generic element $P_{i,j}$ of the product of the two matrices and, after a nontrivial amount of algebra, we find that $P_{i,i} = 1$ and $P_{i,j} = 0$ whenever $i \neq j$.

In some more detail, we start by observing that the columns of $M$ contain the coefficients of $(x-1)^{\left\lfloor \frac{k-1}{2} \right\rfloor}$; hence

$$ M_{n,k} = (-1)^{k-n} \binom{\left\lfloor \frac{k-1}{2} \right\rfloor}{n - \left\lceil \frac{k+1}{2} \right\rceil}  = (-1)^{k-n} \binom{\left\lfloor \frac{k-1}{2} \right\rfloor}{k-n} \enspace. $$

We then write, for $i,j>1$,

$$ P_{i,j} = \sum_{i \leq k \leq j} F_{k,i} M_{k,j} = \sum_{i \leq k \leq j} (-1)^{j-k} \binom{k - \left\lceil \frac{i}{2} \right\rceil}{k-i} \binom{\left\lfloor \frac{j-1}{2} \right\rfloor}{j-k} \enspace. $$

In preparation for further manipulation, we write,

$$ P_{i,j} = (-1)^j \sum_{i \leq k \leq j} (-1)^k \binom{\left\lfloor \frac{j-1}{2} \right\rfloor}{k- \left\lceil \frac{j-1}{2} \right\rceil - 1} \binom{k - \left\lceil \frac{i}{2} \right\rceil - 1}{\left\lfloor \frac{i}{2} \right\rfloor - 1} \enspace. $$

Now we spit cases; for $i>j$ the summation is empty and $P_{i,j}=0$.  For $i=j$ the summation contains one term,

$$ P_{i,i}  = \binom{\left\lfloor \frac{i-1}{2} \right\rfloor}{\left\lfloor \frac{i-1}{2} \right\rfloor} \binom{\left\lfloor \frac{i}{2} \right\rfloor - 1}{\left\lfloor \frac{i}{2} \right\rfloor - 1} = 1 \enspace. $$

Finally, for $j>i$, if $k < \left\lceil \frac{i}{2} \right\rceil + 1$, it is also $k < \left\lceil \frac{j-1}{2} \right\rceil + 1$.  Hence, we can safely extend the summation to all values of $k$.  This allows us to apply a variation of Vadermonde's convolution ((5.24) in [Concrete Mathematics, second edition](https://smile.amazon.com/Concrete-Mathematics-Foundation-Computer-Science/dp/0201558025/ref=smi_www_rco2_go_smi_g2609328962?_encoding=UTF8&%2AVersion%2A=1&%2Aentries%2A=0&ie=UTF8)), which gives,

$$ P_{i,j} = \binom{- \left\lceil \frac{i}{2} \right\rceil + \left\lceil\frac{j-1}{2} \right\rfloor}{\left\lfloor \frac{i}{2} \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{j-1}{2} \right\rfloor - 1} \enspace. $$

For $j>i$, the upper index is non-negative, and the lower index is always greater than the upper index.  Hence $P_{i,j} = 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunatly there was an error in the identity above (last floor was fract 3 and not 2), this answer applies also with the correct identity? Honestly I don't understand how you have used the identity for solving the exercise

Comment: If all goes well, I'll complete the proof today.  Once completed, it should be easier to follow.  But I'd also ask you to point to the step where things get unclear.  The basic approach is the one explained by James Arathoon.  I just used a matrix formulation, which is good for computation and also for the proof.

Comment: Your answer is perfect and really clear, I have one question about the part where you show that $S_{n+2} = S_{n} + S_{n+1}$, I know that the answer may be obvious but I can't understand why when you changed the superior index of the first sommatory from n-1 to n+2 in the binomial inside the sommatory you add 1 to n up and 2 to lower part, thank for everything!

Comment: That's simply because in the upper index $k$ is divided by $2$; $\lceil (k+2)/2 \rceil = \lceil k/2 \rceil + 1$.  Have you given some thought to changing that $3$ back to $2$?